# Where is libappindicator3.so.1?

Tags: google-chrome, centos, lib

I'm trying to install Google-Chrome on CentOS7(Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64).

The file (libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit)) is needed, but there is no such file on the https://pkgs.org/.

```
[leohu@SpaceX Downloads]$ rpm -ivh google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm 
warning: google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 7fac5991: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-66.0.3359.117-1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Google-Chrome : The file (libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit)) is needed

"libappindicator-gtk3" is in the EPEL repo https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

```
# yum install epel-release             (the "extras" must be enabled)
# yum install libappindicator-gtk3
```

If any issues, you can get the latest epel repo files = `epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm` from https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm ... and do `# yum install Downloads/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm` ... ( The version in "extras" is currently epel-release-**7-9**.noarch ).

Comment: Thank you. It works amazingly. But how could you distinguish Linux Packages and EPEL. I'm new with Linux. Thank you!

Comment: Easy to find at http://rpm.pbone.net/ → Advanced Search → tick: CentOS 7 + Redhat EL7 + Scientific Linux 7. ... Besides that, you will find a full EPEL package list here https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/Packages/ ... CentOS 7 package lists http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/

Comment: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/extras/x86_64/Packages/ used to get epel release rpm file for centos7